# How to set up TeamCity to use own HTTP authenticated NuGet service?

Tags: msbuild, nuget, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

a problem is that TeamCity is unable to authorize into NuGet service which runs on same TeamCity instance.

Below you can find how the Build configuration looks now:
[image: Build Step]

I also added Build Feature for NuGet Credentials:
[image: NuGet Credentials]

With this configuration I receive following errors in log:

```
Restoring NuGet package Nuget.Package.Name.0.1.0.41.
Please provide credentials for: http://teamcity-nuget-server.cloudapp.azure.com/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc
UserName:   GET http://www.nuget.org/Packages(Id='Nuget.Package.Name';,Version='0.1.0.41')
NotFound http://www.nuget.org/Packages(Id='Nuget.Package.Name';,Version='0.1.0.41') 194ms
GET http://www.nuget.org/FindPackagesById()?id='Nuget.Package.Name';
NotFound http://www.nuget.org/FindPackagesById()?id='Nuget.Package.Name'; 105ms
WARNING: Unable to find version '0.1.0.41' of package 'Nuget.Package.Name'.
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache: Package 'Nuget.Package.Name.0.1.0.41' is not found on source 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache'.
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\: Package 'Nuget.Package.Name.0.1.0.41' is not found on source 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\'.
http://teamcity-nuget-server.cloudapp.azure.com/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc: Unable to load the service index for source http://teamcity-nuget-server.cloudapp.azure.com/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc.
Cannot prompt for input in non-interactive mode.
http://nuget.org: The V2 feed at 'http://www.nuget.org/FindPackagesById()?id='Nuget.Package.Name'' returned an unexpected status code '404 Not Found'.

Errors in packages.config projects
Unable to find version '0.1.0.41' of package 'Nuget.Package.Name'.
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache: Package 'Nuget.Package.Name.0.1.0.41' is not found on source 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache'.
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\: Package 'Nuget.Package.Name.0.1.0.41' is not found on source 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\'.
http://teamcity-nuget-server.cloudapp.azure.com/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc: Unable to load the service index for source http://teamcity-nuget-server.cloudapp.azure.com/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc.
Cannot prompt for input in non-interactive mode.
http://nuget.org: The V2 feed at 'http://www.nuget.org/FindPackagesById()?id='Nuget.Package.Name'' returned an unexpected status code '404 Not Found'.

NuGet Config files used:
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config

Feeds used:
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\
http://teamcity-nuget-server.cloudapp.azure.com/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc
http://nuget.org
```

I tried several other configurations, i.e using %teamcity.nuget.feed.server% and even %teamcity.nuget.feed.auth.server%. I also tried to remove build feature with NuGet credentials (since documentation says it doesn't need to authenticate with self hosted NuGet service). Tried to remove http://nuget.org source as well. Nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in TeamCity: one with NuGet version 3.3.0 and higher: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-44438 and the second with local agent: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-44479. Please check the tickets linked. You can try to use earlier NuGet version or  try the [workaround](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-44438#comment=27-1451345]).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are using NuGet 3 but the package source is pointing to the v2 Feed.

Update your "NuGet.config" (C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config) with the following package sources:

```
<packageSources>
  <add key="NuGet official package source" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
</packageSources>
```